# backup/sync service for use with mac, iOS, android and QNAP

Tags: macos, backup, sync, qnap

I am looking for a "cloud" backup service that also offers synchronisation of files. I need to be able to select which folders to sync to each device, and how. Also it would be great with archived versions of files, etc.

Should be usable from Mac OSX, Android, iOS devices, as well as a QNAP NAS (4.0 software).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dropbox. QNAP x86-based NAS, like TS-469, supports Dropbox. It uses the official Dropbox Linux client.